# Error while installing virt-manager due to versioning issues

Tags: python, qemu, linux-mint, kvm, libvirt

I was on Linux Mint 19.3 and upgraded to 20 a day ago, and I am now testing all my software to make sure they still work. Virt-manager doesn't work right now (but it does in 19.3), and I am very perplexed as to why. Virsh seems to work fine:

```
kelvin@mint-1:/usr/share$ virsh list --all
 Id   Name            State
--------------------------------
 -    kali            shut off
 -    ubuntu18.04     shut off
 -    ubuntu20.04     shut off
 -    ubuntu20.04.2   shut off
 -    win10           shut off
```

KVM seems to work fine too:

```
kelvin@mint-1:/usr/share$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Libvirtd seems to be working too:

```
kelvin@mint-1:/usr/share$ service libvirtd status
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-07-07 11:09:16 EDT; 1h 2min ago
TriggeredBy: ● libvirtd-ro.socket
             ● libvirtd-admin.socket
             ● libvirtd.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
   Main PID: 16336 (libvirtd)
      Tasks: 25 (limit: 32768)
     Memory: 48.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
             ├─ 1548 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/wifi1.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
             ├─ 1549 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/wifi1.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
             ├─ 1610 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
             ├─ 1613 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
             ├─ 1716 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/wifi2.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
             ├─ 1717 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/wifi2.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
             ├─ 1801 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/wifi3.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
             ├─ 1803 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/wifi3.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
             └─16336 /usr/sbin/libvirtd

Jul 07 11:09:16 mint-1 dnsmasq-dhcp[1548]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/wifi1.hostsfile
Jul 07 11:09:16 mint-1 dnsmasq[1610]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts - 0 addresses
Jul 07 11:09:16 mint-1 dnsmasq-dhcp[1610]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
Jul 07 11:09:16 mint-1 dnsmasq[1801]: read /etc/hosts - 12 addresses
Jul 07 11:09:16 mint-1 dnsmasq[1801]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/wifi3.addnhosts - 0 addresses
Jul 07 11:09:16 mint-1 dnsmasq-dhcp[1801]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/wifi3.hostsfile
Jul 07 11:09:16 mint-1 libvirtd[16336]: libvirt version: 6.0.0, package: 0ubuntu8.1 (Christian Ehrhardt <christian.ehrhardt@canonical.com> Wed, 20 May 2020 06:59:57 +0200)
Jul 07 11:09:16 mint-1 libvirtd[16336]: hostname: mint-1
Jul 07 11:09:16 mint-1 libvirtd[16336]: ignoring dangling symlink '/home/kelvin/.steampath'
Jul 07 11:10:51 mint-1 libvirtd[16336]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
```

Then I decided to run virt-manager:

```
kelvin@mint-1:/usr/share$ virt-manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager", line 19, in <module>
    from virtinst import BuildConfig
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from virtinst.domain import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/domain/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .blkiotune import DomainBlkiotune
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/domain/blkiotune.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..xmlbuilder import XMLBuilder, XMLChildProperty, XMLProperty
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/xmlbuilder.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .xmlapi import XMLAPI
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/xmlapi.py", line 7, in <module>
    import libxml2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libxml2'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 153, in apport_excepthook
    with os.fdopen(os.open(pr_filename,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/_usr_share_virt-manager_virt-manager.1000.crash'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager", line 19, in <module>
    from virtinst import BuildConfig
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from virtinst.domain import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/domain/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .blkiotune import DomainBlkiotune
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/domain/blkiotune.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..xmlbuilder import XMLBuilder, XMLChildProperty, XMLProperty
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/xmlbuilder.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .xmlapi import XMLAPI
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/xmlapi.py", line 7, in <module>
    import libxml2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libxml2'
```

So the problem is clearly missing `libxml2` right? I look everywhere, and what I found out is that `libxml2` is a C library/binary, installed using `apt install libxml2`, and `lxml` is a python binding to `libxml2`, installed using `pip3 install lxml`. All well and good. But then again, it still outputs that error. So I went into the file `/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/xmlapi.py` and change `import libxml2` to `import lxml as libxml2`.

This approach works great, and virt-manager starts up as usual. But then, I can't connect to QEMU/KVM for some reason, so I decided to delete the connection entirely, and recreate the connection again, still using the default URL `qemu:///system`. But then, it can't connect, and it dumps this log:

```
Unable to connect to libvirt qemu:///system.

'virConnect' object has no attribute 'caps'

Libvirt URI is: qemu:///system

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1033, in _open_thread
    self._populate_initial_state()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 991, in _populate_initial_state
    self.get_uri(), self.caps.get_xml())
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 314, in <lambda>
    caps = property(lambda self: getattr(self, "_backend").caps)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/connection.py", line 118, in __getattr__
    return getattr(libvirtconn, attr)
AttributeError: 'virConnect' object has no attribute 'caps'
```

This is the point where it throws an error:

```
def _populate_initial_state(self):
    log.debug("libvirt version=%s",
                  self._backend.local_libvirt_version())
    log.debug("daemon version=%s",
                  self._backend.daemon_version())
    log.debug("conn version=%s", self._backend.conn_version())
    log.debug("%s capabilities:\n%s",
                  self.get_uri(), self.caps.get_xml())
```

I tried to comment out that section, but it still throws an error at another location. The only definition I can see is this:

```
def invalidate_caps(self):
    return self._backend.invalidate_caps()
caps = property(lambda self: getattr(self, "_backend").caps)
```

Right now, I am so deep into this that I feel like I am missing something if I am actually changing the source code. So where was I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution! Following the instructions [here](http://www.calmkart.com/?p=508) (in Chinese, but I'm not Chinese, so chrome automatically translates it for me), I only need to execute `pip3 install libxml2-python3`, and don't have to mess around with changing `import libxml2` to `import lxml`.

Comment: Just as a reference for other people who may run into this. It seems like a package maintainer issue installing the libxml2 module in a different (the wrong?) dist-packages directory. Read more here: https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/issues/116#issuecomment-1288003199